# "AIR Debug Launcher" app is not drag and drop enabled in osx

Tags: events, macos, drag-and-drop, air, adobe

I am doing an AIR app that needs drag and drop functionalities.
And to optimize the workflow the most- I would like to have it possible to drag files into the "AIR Debug Launcher" and react to the dispatching NativeDragEvents. But in OSX this does not work? ex.: the icon in the dock does not react when dragging a file over it (no focus), like photoshop for example does.
Is anybody else experiencing this?
I have tried both the AIR 2.7 ADL and AIR Beta (3.0).
I am using the 2.7 SDK.
Using FDT.

NativeDragManager.isSupported is true.
Compiled AIR app works fine with the events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you must declare the file type associations in the application descriptor file.

so if your AIR application wanted to handle Photoshop files (.psd), you must include this in your application descriptor file:

```
<fileTypes> 
    <fileType> 
        <extension>psd</extension> 
    </fileType> 
</fileTypes>
```

more here:  [AIR application descriptor elements](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fd9)

Comment: Thank you for your answer- the file extensions is not the problem. They have all been added in the descriptor file, and the app works fine when compiled (.air), installed and runned.
The issue with the ADL is that the program it self (.adl/debug tool) does not react to files getting drag over/into it. The example with Photoshop was meant to illustrate what normal behavior of an app that reacts to files getting dragged over/into it.